# What is the best solution for saving images within a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

Initially I wanted to host my application on Heroku, but since the file-system on Heroku is read-only, I would need to store uploaded images on **Amazon S3 or something similar**.

The pictures mostly have mobile phone camera quality (I think something between 500kb - 1MB). I would like to also create thumbnails of those pictures with Rails and save them.

Since I don't know how much traffic I will have, the whole system should be *scalable*.

Is there a better/cheaper *alternative* to the above (Heroku + S3), e.g. storing images in the database or other hosters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on whether you want to stay with a PaaS (i.e. Heroku, Azure, etc.), or if you want to go with a IaaS (i.e. AWS). Given that you stated Heroku, I will assume you want a PaaS. I'm not sure of the exact cost difference between services (but I can get this for you if needed), but combining Heroku + S3 + ([Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) || [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)) = an incredibly fast solution that scales. Then in the future you can look into cutting costs, once you prove your idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes I'm definitely going with Heroku and I'm actually searching for an overview of cost differences between cloud storage services to store images.

Comment: Yes it helped me to understand, but I would like to find some sources where they compare (the costs) of some good PaaS. Do you know where I could find some sources?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a good chart yet, but I will let you know if I come across one. The main thing to note is that the difference in costs are slim, and the main differentiator is what they provide in terms of services, deployability, etc. With that said, I wouldn't spend to much time filtering through your options, and just pick one that suites your needs now. If later on your needs change, you can always switch providers.